# how can i update code on my pc when code owner makes commits

Tags: docker, github, commit, git-commit

For the first time I ran this command `docker pull dafoam/opt-packages:v3.0.8`
to download the DAFoam image. But there have been some commits made by code owner, how to update my DAFoam image, so that I have latest files on my pc.

I think running the above command again does not update files because comamnd prompt says `Image is up to date for dafoam/opt-packages:v3.0.8`
I was expecting that after running this command all of the files of this git will be updated on my pc.
Im sorry if this is a very basic question. Actually I don't have knowledge about github.
https://dafoam.github.io/mydoc_get_started_download_docker.html
https://github.com/mdolab/dafoam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use tag `v3.0.8` you're saying that that's the version you want, even if there are newer versions. To update, you need to use a different tag. The image owner might provide a `latest` tag you can use. But even if you use that, the image isn't updated automatically. You need to pull it yourself, when there are updates.

If you look at the available tags for the image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/dafoam/opt-packages/tags) you can see that there is a `latest` tag that was pushed recently. So if you use `dafoam/opt-packages:latest` you should get the new version